# Varying parameters in SIR python model

Tags: python, variables, parameters, jupyter

I'm modelling a flu pandemic using an adaptation of an SIR model in python. My model includes the vaccination programme, therefore I have a parameter (epsilon) which represents the vaccination roll out rate. I need epsilon to vary between different time intervals. Below is my current code for this section.

```
def epsilon(t):
    return 0.74 if t < 77 else 0.09

epsilon_result = epsilon(t)
        
# A grid of time points (in days)
t = np.linspace(0, 182, 182)

# The SIR model differential equations.
def deriv(y, t, N, beta_s, beta_v, kapa, tau, epsilon_result, gamma, alpha, nu, detla_s, delta_v, p, q):
    S, E_s, V, E_v, I, A, R_i, R_v = y
    dSdt = - beta_s * S * I / N - beta_s * S * delta_s * A / N - epsilon * S
    dVdt = epsilon_result * S - beta_v * V * I / N - beta_v * V * delta_v * A / N - gamma * V * R_v / N
    dE_sdt = beta_s * V * I / N + beta_s * S * delta_s * A / N - kapa * E_s
    dE_vdt = beta_v * V * I / N + beta_v * A / N - kapa * E_s 
    dIdt = p * kapa * E_v - alpha * I + q * tau * E_v
    dAdt = (1-p) * kapa * E_v - nu * A + (1-q) * tau * E_v
    dR_idt = alpha * I + nu * A
    dR_vdt = gamma * V * R_v / N
    return dSdt, dE_sdt, dVdt, dE_vdt, dIdt, dAdt, dR_idt, dR_vdt

# Initial conditions vector
y0 = S0, E_s0, V0, E_v0, I0, A0, R_i0, R_v0

# Integrate the SIR equations over the time grid, t.
ret = odeint(deriv, y0, t, args=(N, beta_s, beta_v, kapa, tau, epsilon_result, gamma, alpha, nu, delta_s, delta_v, p, q))
S, E_s, V, E_v, I, A, R_i, R_v = ret.T
```

This is the error I get.

```
  ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-b43444e01f4c> in <module>
 32     return 0.74 if t < 77 else 0.09
 33 
 ---> 34 epsilon_result = epsilon(t)
 35 
 36 # A grid of time points (in days)

 <ipython-input-11-b43444e01f4c> in epsilon(t)
 30 
 31 def epsilon(t):
 ---> 32     return 0.74 if t < 77 else 0.09
 33 
 34 epsilon_result = epsilon(t)

 ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't put a function call in a function definition

Answer (score 0):

You have the time array `t` hanging around from a previous failed run of the script. With a clean workspace you would get the error that `t` is not defined. The error is exactly what it says, you pass an array to a function that can not work in array mode.

But what you actually want is something different that avoids any immediate work-arounds:

```
# The SIR model differential equations.
def deriv(y, t, N, beta_s, beta_v, kapa, tau, epsilon, gamma, alpha, nu, detla_s, delta_v, p, q):
    S, E_s, V, E_v, I, A, R_i, R_v = y
    #<<<--- inserted here
    epsilon_result = epsilon(t)
    #>>>---
    dSdt = - beta_s * S * I / N - beta_s * S * delta_s * A / N - epsilon * S
    ...
```

In this way the function `epsilon` is always called with only a scalar `t`, so that its contents works as intended.